# Juju: how to get a config option value?

Tags: juju, maas

We can set a config option by

```
juju set <service-name> <config-option>
```

but can i get a config-option **value** that i already set using juju set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the configuration values of a service by running `juju get <service-name>`. That will return a yaml dump of the services config, and the current value stored in the `value` key.

Comment: Thank Adam. Can we get the value of a specific config parameter by $ juju get ? instead of getting the yaml dump of the services config

Comment: Not as a parameter of the `juju get` command, but you could use shyaml (a python package installable via pip), so you could do something like `juju get wordpress | shyaml get-value settings.engine`.